# Использование Camunda engine с Spring MVC

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, camunda

Есть необходимость организовать электронный документооборот.Возможно ли  использовать  Camunda engine для бизнес процессов и статусов и Spring MVC в качестве страниц использовать свой дизайн  ? Может не понятно задал вопрос с Camunda  не работал.

Comment: Да, это возможно и подробно описано в документации.

Comment: Спасибо, пойду изучать.